# Root mode in Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: android

I need to use the package manager in adb.
For that how do i enable the root permission on android samsung galaxy s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [`z4root`](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=833953).

Comment: I am trying the disable the browser from adb:-                    pm disable com.android.browser but it returns the following execv /system/xbin/procrank returned -1   execv /system/xbin/librank returned -1           /mnt/.lfs:Function not implemented execv /system/bin/parse_radio_log returned -1 [1] Killed pm disable com.android.browser